# Set minimum and exact length in bytes of column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How can one set the column value length to a minimum and/or exact length using MS SQL Management Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For character datatypes (char/nchar/varchar/nvarchar), you set the length:
[image]

Remember that for `char` and `nchar`, you'll ALWAYS be allocated the *x* bytes space, and your string will be padded. `nchar` always has 2 *x* allocated, but the string length will be as you specify.

For string-length minimums, that really should be left to the application.

SQL Server does allow you to put a constraint on a column.

In this example, the constraint is that the column value be >= 10.

Simply write a TSQL expression in the Expression field.

- `LEN(myColumn) = 20` - the value being inserted/updated in the column is length of 20.
- `LEN(RTRIM(LRTIM(myColumn))) = 20` - the value being inserted/updated in the column is length of 20, with all leading/trailing whitespace removed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking here. If you are asking how to make sure the user only enters a certain number of characters into a column of a table, SSMS is not the tool to do this. You would need to enforce this at the database level, through a check constraint, for example. Or through your application.